# Getting count of text areas having multiple names for a classname

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, textarea, erb

In one of the erb template in my Rails application, I am generating a text area dynamically from a loop and the number of text areas just depends on the user. Below is the text area given.

```
<%= text_area_tag "fields[#{i}][name]",'', :class=>"validate[required,funcCall[checkHELLO]] text-input options", :style=>"width:115px; height:19px; border:#d1d1d1 1px solid;" %>
```

As you can see, the name is different for different text area and is dynamically generated throgh the loop. Class name is the same, but having multiple names and it is integrated with TinyMCE. I need to get the content of these text areas. But, If I give an id to identify the text area, it will be the same for all text area since it is generated from a loop. I need some way to get the contents of these text areas. Can anyone help me for the same?

Thanks :)-

Answer (score 1):

You have a tinymce editor instance for each of your textareas, corrext?
In this case they will have to have different ids to (otherwise tinymce wouldn't load a second one with the same id).

This taken into account you simply can loops through all available editors and get their ids - which coresponds to the ids of your textarea:

```
for (i=0; i<tinymce.editors.length;i++){
    console.log('A textarea has id:' + tinymce.editors[i].id);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add id for the text field with id of user table; like this,

```
<%= text_area_tag "fields[#{i}][name]",'',id: i, :class=>"validate[required,funcCall[checkHELLO]] text-input options", :style=>"width:115px; height:19px; border:#d1d1d1 1px solid;" %>
```

Then call with this id.

Comment: user table?? what is this?

Comment: I just mentioned one model name. you can assume with your model that is using for this loop.